# Character Frequency in a String

Tags: code-golf, string, counting

Given a string of printable ASCII, output the frequency of each character in that string.

### The Challenge

- Input is given as a string of printable ASCII characters (decimal `[32-126]` inclusive).
- Output the frequency of each character, in ASCII order.
- The output must have a format similar to `[character][separator][count]`. Provided that there is a single, non-newline separating string between the character and its frequency, it is a valid output.
- Output can be a single string, multiple strings, list of 2-tuples, array of tuples, etc.
- Input and output can be given [using any convenient method.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest in bytes wins.

### Sample I/O

```
abcd
//outputs
a: 1
b: 1
c: 1
d: 1
```

```
Over 9001!
//outputs
  [ 1
! [ 1
0 [ 2
1 [ 1
9 [ 1
O [ 1
e [ 1
r [ 1
v [ 1
```

```
--<-<<+[+[<+>--->->->-<<<]>]<<--.<++++++.<<-..<<.<+.>>.>>.<<<.+++.>>.>>-.<<<+.
//outputs (as 2-tuples)
(+,14),(-,13),(.,13),(<,21),(>,13),([,2),(],2)
```

```
Su3OH39IguWH
//outputs (as 2d array)
[[3,2],[9,1],[H,2],[I,1],[O,1],[S,1],[W,1],[g,1],[u,2]]
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161921/alphabet-histogram) and [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55880/find-the-occurrences-of-a-character-in-an-input-string).

Comment: *Output the frequency of each character, in ASCII order.* but `e` after `v`‽

Comment: May I output `a,1b,2c,3`?

Comment: Could I use `PETSCII` instead? -> https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/PETSCII 
Also, do you mean true `ASCII` (7-bit), or simply `ASCII`-compatible, like extended `ASCII` or `UTF-8`?

Comment: I assume the output be for `aAbBcCdD` will it be `A:1, B:1, C:1, D:1, a:1, b:1 c:1, d:1` - your examples of input/output has a type as Adam has mentioned above.

Comment: You say there is a single character separator yet your first two examples use 2 and 3 character separators.  Is the mistake in the spec or the examples?

Comment: @tsh No, but `a,1 b,2 c,3` is a valid output

Comment: @ShaunBebbers ooo that's something. I'll allow it. ASCII-compatibles are also fine, provided you say what encoding it is.

Comment: May we assume nonempty input?

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya Yes.

Comment: Can there be any leading/trailing characters on the output? before the first line or after the last line?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ah-ha, the very challenge I thought of but couldn't find when I saw this in the Sandbox so,   in a rare occurrence for me, I'm gonna swing my hammer as I don't think the requirement that the output be sorted makes this significantly different.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>50, 43</s>, 41 bytes

```python
lambda s:{c:s.count(c)for c in sorted(s)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqjrZqlgvOb80r0QjWTMtv0ghWSEzT6E4v6gkNUWjWLP2f0FRJlAuTUMpMSk5JVFJU/M/AA)

Comment: You could save 7 bytes by switching to a list of 2-tuples (replace `c+","+str(s.count(c))` with `(c,s.count(c))`), since python sorts tuples by their first elements. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqji/qCQ1RaNaI1mnWC85vzSvRCNZUzMtv0ghWSEzT6G4VvN/QVEmUDRNQykxKTklUUlT8z8A)

Comment: You can save 2 bytes using zip() and map() (can't access TIO where I am, sorry): `lambda s:sorted({*zip(s,map(s.count,s))})`

Comment: You can save two brackets (2 bytes) by using a dict and that more recent versions of Python 3 retain insertion order. `lambda s:{c:s.count(c)for c in sorted(s)}`

Answer (score 9):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
SÖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxDcBADAJ3@daC4mvkJVK@vv8myjZZKIM5tgEhneA594y4vjdiAIJky5bMAXhb0vYtAZS1mMCsZLpX8sMamlBoHD8)

```
      implicit input
S     sort string
 Ö    run-length encoding
      implicitly print
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```
lambda s:sorted({*zip(s,map(s.count,s))})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHYqji/qCQ1RaNaqyqzQKNYJzcRSOol55fmlegUa2rWav4vKMrMK9FI01BKTEpOSVTS1PwPAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
({.;#)/.~@/:~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcqxCsJADAbgvU8RdIgl5q/zmYaC4OTkWjpotYiLDyD01c/cDSb5Ax/JO2/AC/WJmPZ0oBRR0Ol6OefdF8dt22EdurTmtmme8@tDC/HtPj/4L1VTMxllNHFV9dpmNvlkpgqTWgggVhjuZeIH5VClhQLOPw)

- `@/:~` sort the input and...
- `/.~` partition it into groups of like items.  Apply the following to each group...
- `({.;#)` take the first element `{.` and link it `;` to the number of items in the group `#`

Comment: Nice! I forgot about `/.`, my solution with `=` was significantly longer: `(;/@~.,.1;/@:#.=)@/:~`

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
ọo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/@Hu3vz//6OVEpOSU5R0lPzLUosULA0MDBWBHF1dG10bG@1o7WgbbTtdXV07MLSxsYm1i7Wx0dXVs9EGAz0gRw9IAPl6dnYgBFSjB5IA83RBXG09oIHBpcb@HsaWnuml4R5KsQA)

```
ọ     Occurrences,
 o    sorted.
```

It's essentially the same as using an RLE builtin with the sorting requirement, but if the output could be in any order it would just be `ọ`.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 5 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function, returning a two-column table, which by default prints with space as separator between character and count, and line break after each entry.

```apl
,∘≢⌸∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X@dRx4xHnYse9ex41LH8f9qjtgmPevse9U319H/U1XxovfGjtolAXnCQM5AM8fAM/p@moJ6YlJyizqWrq8sF5PiXpRYpWBoYGCrChXR1bXRtbLSjtaNttO2AYnZgaGNjE2sXa2Ojq6tnow0GekCOHpAA8vXs7EAIqEYPJAHm6YK42npwY4NLjf09jC0900vDPdQB)

`,` character followed

`∘` by

`≢` its tally

`⌸` for each unique character

`∧` in ascending order

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>52</s> 49 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to cole!*

```hs
import Data.List
map((,).nub<*>length).group.sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCoAgEADQ3a@4oqEipMYgmxqDvuECK0lNzrPft978Loy3tjZn48JDDAsyytVEFodyGOq6a6RP@9TOVvuTr0ae9KQg45@zcGg8KAhkPEMFB5TbqwnGvh@KMn8)

I know this is too long (especially that import), but I'm new at Haskell golfing and hoping to get better! Outputs as a list of tuples of `(character, count)` (note the `character` is `String`, not a `Char`).

Comment: Beat me by a few minutes. [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##Dco5DoAgEADAnldsqMAYXiBWln5iTbgixwaW96NTT8TxupzXSoVaZ7iQ0dxpsPC2ICm1a1Pnc2xndjVw1Cb0NsmMPy9RMFWwQD1VBuVBshss9foA)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the output type is `[(String, Int)]`, but I think that's acceptable (not `[(Char, Int)]` like in your first answer). I don't know edit-quette very well here, so I hope my edit to clarify this was not in bad taste

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```perl6
*.comb.Bag.sort
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxC4MwFIT3/Ip0kdbwHhahIL5m6GQnhw4dxCHaKAVTJdaCvz5NcnccfNwt2k4XZ3aeDPzqUuxn0@FNjbjO9utKNr0/ekWjlmOKyYCr2k9Odf2L1T9teZFl5wMDICASjWhISACQ0UTUypYIAElEoQf05RmlDPEfDEMkCCiQPba8rvLiPm7P6g8)

Anonymous code block that takes a string and returns a list of pairs, where the key is the character and the value is the number of occurrences.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
*.comb           # Decompose into characters
      .Bag       # Group into unordered bag of character => occurrences
          .sort  # Sort by character
```

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>8</s> 4 bytes

```
$e`p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1f9F8lNaHg///EpOSURAA)

-3 bytes thanks to Jonah, and -1 byte from rule interpretation.

A perfect challenge for CJam. <s>I had hoped that the RLE encode operator would output `[char, count]`, but the order was reversed. Otherwise it would have been a 5-byter.</s> After Jonah's comment, I switched the order of the output. <s>I'm not sure if the first read should be counted, since the standard rules permit input to be on the stack at the start of the program. If that's the case, this answer is one byte shorter.</s> From [this meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/79994), I concluded that the read could be placed in the header. Otherwise I could modify the script to be a function without changing the byte count.

### Explanation

```
 $       sort string
  e`     RLE-encode (transforms "aabc" to [[2, "a"], [1, "b"], [1, "c"]]
    p    print
```

**Open question**: would something [like this](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fVP1fJTXhf21dwf/EpOSURAA) be allowed if transforming the answer to a function, or should the brackets be included in the byte count?

Comment: "Provided that there is a single, non-newline separating character between the character and its frequency, it is a valid output." -- combined with the adjective "similar to," I read this as saying that the order doesn't matter.  Which means you could drop the reversing.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <sup><s>27</s></sup> <sup><s>22</s></sup> 20 bytes

```bash
fold -1|sort|uniq -c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc3BCsIwDAbg@54ityrlD3j/yYuMHbbOMkEsOj1Zn722ZUlI@Eggy7xvJcrpLN8S030VXPKeXu/8edyeglB@w3ANWxI3L2F1kiUedscECNKPfqQ3ANaT5GQTCSh9D63Q2qrVrFW90bboQqPX/qH8AQ)

*-5 bytes thanks to Neil*

*-2 bytes thanks to Digital Trauma*

Comment: Why not take input on STDIN?

Comment: Thanks @Neil, updated.

Comment: `fold -1` instead of `grep -o .` [saves 2](https://tio.run/##Lc3BCsIwDAbg@54ityrlD3j/yYuMHbbOMkEsOj1Zn722ZUlI@Eggy7xvJcrpLN8S030VXPKeXu/8edyeglB@w3ANWxI3L2F1kiUedscECNKPfqQ3ANaT5GQTCSh9D63Q2qrVrFW90bboQqPX/qH8AQ)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma nice.  updated.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 3 bytes

```
ṢŒr
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkVHJxX9P9zu/v9/cKmxv4expWd6abgHAA)

A monadic link taking the string as its argument. Returns a list of lists, each one containing the character and count. The footer formats this as a grid.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
r8S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v8gi@P9/Jf@y1CIFSwMDQ0UlAA)

Simply run-length encodes (`r8`) the sorted (`S`) input. Output is a list of tuples of `[frequency, character]`.

Answer (score 4):

## T-SQL 2008 query, 130 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ varchar(2000)='kabcdda'

SELECT w,sum(1)FROM(SELECT
substring(@,number+1,1)FROM
spt_values WHERE type='P'and
number<len(@))x(w)GROUP BY w
ORDER BY ascii(w)
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/HBX36121)**

Comment: Your order by is alphabetical, but it should be in ascii order. it should be `ORDER BY ascii(w)`

Comment: @Einacio thanks, I had missed that part of the question. I corrected as you suggested

Comment: If your server is set to a *binary collation* like `Latin1_General_BIN` (which is not the default), sort order would be by ASCII code, without have to explicitly use the `ASCII` function. That does add an additional requirement to the answer (although you're already requiring this to be run in the `master` database, by your use of the `master.dbo.spt_values` system table). Good answer, though. SQL definitely needs a better built-in numbers table.

Comment: @BradC interesting idea, using that collation, that would be kind of a big assumption. Using master database seems more legitimate though, best practice for me is not assigning users a default database. Last time I tried that, I was unable to log in with that user after the default database had been removed - I am not aware whether this issue has been fixed. I agree we need a better build in number table, this could easily be a calendar table as well.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk [I've had answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156967/157069#157069) where I had to specify "this only works with a case sensitive collation" or something, so it does narrow the scope, like when you have to specify the SQL version; in your case adding the extra bytes for the `ASCII` function is probably a better approach. Similarly, [I try to specify when my code needs to be run in a particular database](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127261/unique-is-cheap/153627#153627), so that it doesn't fail if someone tries it in a different context.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 57 bytes

```php
foreach(count_chars($argn,1)as$a=>$b)echo chr($a)," $b
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BasMwDIbvfgotGNLgyLT0VKK6p0IGgxR22CELxfGy@pQEO9ll7Nkzx9kkIfRJ@oVGOy50Ge3IGJ86P3k4Q80AUt2ajzRfq@qrc3Da7w9PGyMSEola1CQUIqroRNSohghRkogmA8iQAkul1gg7ch1EwhWF3G6@zseqPJ6eH/NbmbKmYOxzcJ02dgd/b2kPXLtHDxl8B0Vn7LA1criVt/u1eimWf40Z5n66G6ud3207h0x7rs@Kt1lUGuvCJMsT4C1LiiU2k/c@KdjP8gs)

Input via `STDIN`, run with `php -F`:

```php
$ echo Su3OH39IguWH|php -F cc.php
3 2
9 1
H 2
I 1
O 1
S 1
W 1
g 1
u 2
```

Fun fact: this challenge is basically the [**Example 1**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php#refsect1-function.count-chars-examples) on the PHP docs for [`count_chars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php#refsect1-function.count-chars-examples).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 58 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...s].sort().flatMap(c=>c>p?[p=[c,1]]:p[1]++&&[],p=[])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY3PCsIwDIfvPoV6kJaa4PCkZPWqgu7gwUPpoXZ/mIy1rFPw6We3BxCT8IMv@SBP8zbBdrXvoXV5MZTpEFKpEDFoDK7rGceyMf3FeGZTaaU/KJ8qu0603nuVaCFWK6XXcaf5YF0bXFNg4yp2vmVXDH1Xt1VdfljJluZhc7PknM9@e9m76Oa7zSZZ/CEDEBAJJRQJCQByaiLSUhMBIImpMALGiIxSjhMdHA8TwYgC/3h4e22z43Z3ql7346gPXw)

Thanks Shaggy, -1 byte.

---

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 18 bytes

```javascript
O`.
(.)\1*
$1,$.&¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrBCYAwFEPvziGifhPoPfwVHEALevDgxYM4mwO4WG2bhMAjuY/nvPaQ0ryx6TmsYWzaMLXsvjclQJBssUXmALxaUvQoAZRVMQNzZaZ7Sf6wDJVQ0PgD)

I don't speak Retina. I just translated above JavaScript answer to Retina with some searching.

Thanks to Cows quack, -3 bytes.

Comment: `$.($&)` can become `$.&`

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##VYwxD4IwEIV3f4U6tdY7MU4kR2edHBwcsIkVKoIKpK0Gfz0WBhPvLi/53nu5Sr@1y2zZenBtmRv7bOq7@fTXpHeJTBHRKXSN9Yxj1ZT1@YxP7bMbWzHkp/ViVfBgtKwL5S6N1LLDh6kLf1O8b21Ze3Zlc33Jcj3nfPJz9m9jp3EUrWd/NgABkUhFSkICgByXiJRURABIYhwMgEECo5TDhQ4OwUgwoMC/14fXZr/dxLviddyGoP8C)

Comment: @Shaggy Nice idea. And I moved one more step based on that.

Comment: Are there special requirements for the JS solution?
Doesn't work on my latest Chrome (neither in TIO, nor dev tools) - I get an array of correct length, but filled with nulls.

Comment: @targumon Just fixed it. Seems posted wrong version... It should work on TIO and most recent Chrome now ...

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>27</s> <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```powershell
$args[0]|sort|group
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL042iC2pji/qKQmvSi/tOD///8a0ckZiUXRsbHqwaXG/h7Glp7ppeEeGeqaAA)

Exactly what it says on the tin. Takes input `$args[0]` via splatting (manifests on TIO as a `[char[]]`), `sort`s it, then `group-object` it into a grouping.

*-8 bytes thanks to mazzy*

Comment: That output is perfectly fine.

Comment: is a splatted string 'any convenient method'? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9uKY4v6ikJr0ov7Tgfy0Xl0qxgq2CenCpsb@HsaVnemm4R4Y6F5eyQnFBTmJJSWZeuqKiIpeaSpqCQ7HCfwA "PowerShell – Try It Online") another word, is a char array a representation of a string?

Comment: @mazzy Splatting works, but then you need to count the name of the script block, so we only save a byte. Still, a byte is a byte!

Comment: why? you can save `$args|sort|group` to a file with `.ps1` extension and call this script file as usually. The splatting works with a script file too.

Comment: @mazzy I didn't know that. How would that work on TIO? You can't use `@'` because that's a here-string.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I think TIO does not have splatting functionality. Powershell have. That's why we have to use a footer section on TIO instead an argument section. My question is whether the character array (args after splatting) can be treated as a string in this task?

Comment: @mazzy Yes, a `[char[]]` can be called [a string](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/42963) per Meta consensus. Do you mean something [like this?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL042iC2pji/qKQmvSi/tOD///8a0ckZiUXRsbHqwaXG/h7Glp7ppeEeGeqaAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: yes. thanks. it would be nice if TIO could use splatting.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>94</strike> 91 bytes

Thanks to Ourous and ceilingcat for their suggestions.

To get the non-newline separator, I'm making use of the fact that negative numbers get a "-" for free! :-)

```c
f(char*s){char c[255]={},i=31;for(;*s;)c[*s++]--;for(;++i>0;)c[i]&&printf("%c%d ",i,c[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BboMwDEDv/QoPqVWIcUSHeqiS5tydethhB8SBpUAjbawK0B0Q354ldLaV@D1bsqHOGO9bZm6140M6xx9M@Xo4VKd5yeyp2Mv2xzHJB5makg@IFdFTIVqdR2ur3e7ubD@2LNma7RWSzGZRp3LxQcN3bXsWm9p1JoP1COcBHinMG4Dfm/1qGEf8V9Cy51TCfRoHliShWzZh0zXj5HrI5Wbxvv40V395NA6Oeb5/8USKlMISS4WaiPSaSqlKV0oRCYVriAAiPIGF1rHCjoiDlSgiCv8@FZdzcXzrpo/zHw)

Comment: 93 bytes by moving `i=31` into the declaration: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1Nb4MwDIbv/AoPqVVIcESLqqmKy7k79bDDDogDS4FG2lgVoDsgfnuW0NmW5ef1l8ZOa@dapm@15UMym34EXe4Ph@o0Z0tqTvlOtT@WKT6oRJd8EKJCfEpCGNrtX4Nuqu32bv1yy@KN3lwhTk0a5EQtLtz8rk3PQlHbTqcQ3gHnHh4JzBHA7818NYwL8S9By55dBfdpHFgc@2qJ/KRtxsn2kKloca7@1Fd3eTQWjlm2e3GIhESiFCWJAhGL1YmoKioiREliNelB@uRZFkUIPyNDYyUMKKR7n/LLOT@@ddPH@Q8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: That's clever using negative counting like that.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 34 bytes

```
KeySortBy[ToCharacterCode]@*Counts
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxC8IwEIX3/ApNwcF4UXEqnKHYRXFQUXCIGWKNtkMbiKkg4m@vSQffHY/7uLtXa1@aWvuq0N192W3N@2idX73lyealdrrwxuX2ZlQ2zm3b@Gd3aCvjJSF7VzVe0gulKBIUcQBxz/5fzyxRo2n2IVRfixudELp7GTdIZ7P5MBIAAiKTTCITACD6QkQlFCIAR9aLB@DBAnMhYocbHhc9QUTGY@KxXezWi3TzaM9rSr6EqO4H)

Returns an association.

---

```
SortBy[ToCharacterCode@@#&]@*Tally
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwxC8IwEIX3/ApNwcF4sdKpcIagi04qFhxihlijLVQLMRWK@Ntr08F3x@M@7u49jC/sw/gyN91t2R1r51etyup1YZzJvXXr@mqljCZaTjNTVW13aErrFSF7Vz69omdKUUQowgDiJv@PLxnpyVx@CDWX/EpnhO7e1o3SOF6MAwEgIDLFFDIBAGIoRNRCIwJwZIN4D7y3nrkQofsbHhYDQUDGQ@KxSXabJN3em9OGki8huvsB)

Returns a list.

Comment: Are you sure it's within the rules to put `Characters` into the footer instead of into the code? I think it would be better to use `CharacterCounts` instead of `Counts`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <strike>63</strike> 61 bytes

```cs
s=>s.OrderBy(c=>c).GroupBy(c=>c).Select(g=>(g.Key,g.Count()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwDIbvPkXZqaNLXsA0BwUFPXjw4EE9SNeNgnbSdsKevnYTTELg4w9/fhPBRJd3ozcUU3C@b9rJP17OsOiEzlFzxFNobdhM0mg2Ne7DML7/dLZPa5LsNcsej3ZqetwOo0@yruu8Xq0@jyCSjUloUQEQEKmrupJiAOCliejOdyIAJLUUFsCyCiPzPOUGZ2EhmFFhVdwvwSUrf8HxMDgvq5uvGtHJ@WeJsM5f)

Thanks to Expired Data for pointing me towards the C# Interactive Compiler and for showing me the power of dynamics.

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY4xDsIwDEX3niLqlCi1L1DHAyAGFgYGBmCo0rSKBKmUBERPX9JiW5af/GV/m8AmvxzfwVLK0Yex6efQvbxlMQizJMMJz7F3cTdLa9gqPPiUfbBZKry4pyvDaFiOTcL99A5Zfg1/jRmVUktbVZ8uiuxSFkbUAARE@qZvpBkAeEsievCDCABJb4EFsLTCyLxW0eC62AhW1FiX69fos5N/43iafJD1PdSNGOT6s1holx8 "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: by the way it's not the fact that it's dynamic that it saves 2 bytes, you could make the return type the correct tuple type, I'm just lazy and like to return dynamic when golfing in case I change my mind about what type I want to return!

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), 9 bytes

**Solution:**

```
#:'=x@<x:
```

**Example:**

```
q)k)#:'=x@<x:"Over 9001!"
 | 1
!| 1
0| 2
1| 1
9| 1
O| 1
e| 1
r| 1
v| 1
```

**Explanation:**

```
#:'=x@<x: / the solution
       x: / store input as x
      <   / indices to sort ascending
    x@    / apply (@) to x
   =      / group same values
#:'       / count (#:) each (')
```

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <strike>128</strike> 114 bytes

```
->>,[[-[>>+<<-]>>]>+<+[-<<+]->>,]+[+>[<--.++<<+++++++[>++++++++<-]>++.[-]++++++[>>++++++++<<-]>>.[-].]<[>>+<<-]>>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxLCoAwDESv0v2YniAEXHqGkIUWhaJ2UfH81fpBZ/XgzcyQ@5imPcylkEijSioCZjIROwFKzLDqDApRJvI4C7ij8gDqBPBK9ppPXXdVeePffymdW@I8unYdcwx9cuu@xXAA)

How it works:

```
-                                          sets cell 0 to 255, which is used to move back to cell 2 later on
>>                                         moves to cell 2
,[                                         we load our first input and loop until there are no more characters to load
[-[>>+<<-]>>]                              keeps moving forward skipping every other cell until it has moved forward the ASCII value of the most recently loaded character  
>+<                                        adds one to the next cell for the purpose of later looking at to see how many of that character was entered
+[-<<+]->>                                 goes back to cell 2
,]                                         loads in next character and repeats process if there are remaining characters

+[+>[                                      checks IF the next cell has a value other than 0
<--.                                       then, if true, it prints the ASCII value of the previous cells contents
++<<+++++++[>++++++++<-]>++.               then print ":"
[-]++++++[>>++++++++<<-]>>.                then print the number value of the contents of the current cell
[-].]                                      then print a null character and leaves the if statement
<[>>+<<-]>>]                               continues the same process skipping every other cell, until it repeats 255 times
```

Thanks to Jo King, -14 bytes.

This is my second brainfuck program, first being hello world, and first time golfing, so please let me know what I can do to improve my program and answer!

Comment: You aren't printing a space, you're printing a nul byte. This also won't handle double digits, for example 10 of a character will print `;` not `10`. You can also shorten the `:` generation somewhat

Comment: Thanks!  I shortened the ":" generation, and will try to allow it to print double digits.  Are there any problems associated with printing a null byte?

Answer (score 2):

## APL(NARS), 26 chars, 52 bytes

```
{m,¨+/¨{w=⍵}¨m←k[⍋k←∪w←⍵]}
```

test:

```
  ⎕fmt{m,¨+/¨{w=⍵}¨m←k[⍋k←∪w←⍵]}'is, this good or not?'
┌12─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐ ┌2───┐│
││   4│ │ , 1│ │ ? 1│ │ d 1│ │ g 1│ │ h 1│ │ i 2│ │ n 1│ │ o 4│ │ r 1│ │ s 2│ │ t 2││
│└+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘ └+───┘2
└∊──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

  {m,¨+/¨{w=⍵}¨m←k[⍋k←∪w←⍵]}
                     k←∪w←⍵     copy the argument in w, k is the argument that has unique elements
               m←k[⍋       ]    copy k order, in m, (so m is argument unique ordered)
         {w=⍵}¨m                see each element of m in w, so each element of m generate a len(w) bit list 
      +/¨                       sum each bit list above obtain the number of element of m in w
   m,¨                          make couples
```

Comment: What a programmer want is few primitive that combine well in resolve a problem, and a visual lay out and eventually comments, for explain better...so space and indentation should be good...

Comment: I agree, so use those tools that APL gives you: `{k,¨+/⍵∘.=⍨k←∪⍵[⍋⍵]}`

Comment: @Adám I prefer to order unique of the array on all the array...

Comment: If you prefer a longer solution, then your solution is not a serious contender, and it becomes eligible for deletion!

Comment: Why is this 52 bytes? Does APL/NARS not have [SBCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork I do not know... They say Nars use 16bit character set

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 60 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$s=sort[(c,sum[1\\k<-s|k==c])\\c<-removeDup s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvBCsMgDAbg@57CQ6EbLsLu0VN3GOzWo3oQ60Zp1VLbwmDPPmebhB8@ktjRmZB97NbREW/6kHs/xXkh7dLdw3aqEk@F8myvafXyptSAkL4D51ZflLIIs/Nxc806kaRzu5jyy0lFZA2AgEgllUgFAIijEVELjQjAkB7FCliJYibEPuWG7YtDsJOyWueffY3mnTI8nrn5BON7m/4)

Defines the function `$ :: [Char] -> [(Char, Int)]` giving the result as a list of 2-Tuples.
Uses the element-wise behavior of `<` and thus `sort` on Tuples to ensure codepoint ordering.

Answer (score 1):

## [sfk](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html), <s>124</s> <s>87</s> 84 bytes

```
xed -i
+chars
+count -same -case
+xed "_?????*x*[white]?_[parts 6,3,1]_"
+sort -case
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvRCsMgDEXf/QrpY9MExmBPwX6IiEjnaBlbh7Gsf@/U3RsSDvdGHs9SznjXuClY1pCknv14Z40SXlHjEiQqaI3Bz03jOdrvuuXoZm8/IWXRt@k6XZwfFMie8v@nFERGZrBgGQwimm5mdsYxIxJDF1WguiqTMW1qh1rQCRsC/QA)

Gives output in the form `[character]x[count]` with `count` padded to 5 digits.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 57 bytes

Outputs a 2D-Array. Had to implement a quick & dirty fix for the sorting so I'll need to come back to try to golf that.

```javascript
s=>[...s].map(o=x=>o[x]=-~o[x])&&Object.entries(o).sort()
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##RY6xjsIwDIb3PgW3oETBFicmTk5mmDrccEOuUkoJqBXEqCmo0716LylC2Jb9f7Jl/V39qGPTt7cBAh/9dNJT1MYiYqzwWt8E61EbtmOl4S8PuVyWh843A/ow9K2PgiVG7gchp4ZD5IvHC5@FLVx9aI5uVbjy4fvFdr3@/MgEQECkrLKkDACYOYmoMhURAJKaAxNgaonRmFzpBvNiJsioMH/8vm/K3Wa7P99/dq542k6mT2KULz1ix21wXwsnn@o3vFXW0z8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＥΦγ№θι⁺⁺ι №θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUDDLTOnJLVII11HwTm/FChWqKOQqampoxCQU1qsASYydRSUFJQ0URVoalqDTMlPL0rMzc3MS1cIKK2qykktVlADKktJVXDPz0nj@q9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  γ             Printable ASCII
 Φ              Filtered where non-zero
   №            Count of
     ι          Current character in
    θ           Input string
Ｅ               Map over filtered characters
        ι       Current character
       ⁺        Plus a space
      ⁺         Plus
          №     Count of
            ι   Current character in
           θ    Input string
                Implicitly output on separate lines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
ü
mÎíUmÊ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/Aptzu1Vbco&input=Ik92ZXIgOTAwMSEiCi1S)

```
ü\nmÎíUmÊ     :Implicit input of string U
ü             :Split, sort and partition by value
 \n           :Reassign to U
   m          :Map
    Î         :  First element
     í        :Interleave with
      UmÊ     :  Map lengths of U
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 75 bytes

```
fun String.c()=toCharArray().sorted().map{Pair(it,count{s->it==s})}.toSet()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwEETP9iuW0kMCth8gtiDiwZugx162TWyDupFkC0rIt8dWwZnLwAyPuVm@G0rpOhGc2Rkaql7Imu1@RLdzDt9CVt461moOD3yGExonDK97OxEHXzaG69pHGSu2Z81CflkPNCTQDX4DX8r2B28khCxbLUV1te6A/XgkpV9aQTBrXTbwnGd8J5FftGcoDJRQ6JZaKoJersWWcgkxy2JK6BV2/Yhdwr9Shx0Os73yatEH)

Comment: Replace `Pair(it,count{s->it==s})` with `it to count{s->it==s}`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 82 bytes

```java
s->s.stream().sorted().distinct().map(c->c+" "+s.stream().filter(x->c==x).count())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVA9T8MwEN3zK06ZHGjcvW2yVCAGEEPZEMPVcVoHJ47sS9UK9beHy4cqBAzW2e/de/fOFZ4wrYrP3tSt8wQVv2VHxsq7dfQHK7tGkXHNv2Qgr7EeKGUxBHhB08BXBNB2e2sUBELicnKmgJo5sSNvmsP7B6A/hGRsBXicR2yeTaDN9ogeFWmfL3aj/WYS5TmUkEV9SPMwDxaJDBxIF3wpWGvYh681tkKlubqPIb7/0Vsay7bizFSWnROpXNdwf9Kvxxi3bKQDBcjmdADxk7bWxYtouZwB3KsiHtnrpC2dFyf0o3Q1GSQ3/a@1@Fc8uw9NUjEapshv7nVfCQVpDmKAEzUktFbzTtupOh8kucGOU69n91Ji29qLYFde0fkHVEexuwTStXQdrVYtr0W2mQXXaDjX/hs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
¬ü ®âZl
```

[Test it online!](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rPwgruJabA&input=IlN1M09IMzlJZ3VXSCIKLVI)

Comment: You can drop the `¬` now.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 46 bytes

```
f x=[(c,sum[1|d<-x,d==c])|c<-[' '..],elem c x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYrRCsMgFEN/5VIG3dB7Ye/RHxEfirWsTMtYV/Ch/@60SQgckte0v2NKtS5UjLsHvR/ZPc8ZXPRsTPCPM4DdSKOI1zHFTIGKr3laNzL0@a7bj2600MAMBpRTDsoys70MwFsPMAvUJWkgrRqLtT3tI324iDsqGeof)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-n`, 43 bytes

```ruby
p$_.chars.uniq.sort.map{|c|[c,$_.count(c)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYpLDgIxDEMvwwIUkhNYuUhVoaEbZkFb@lkghqsT2tqWpSe79PvbLJ9uEh5bqdLj/pKaSpPnlj9HOFy4zjH12M7h4r9mzGCAHDmQMrMuA/DqAWYBLckAGTVYVGfGR@awiCeS/FJue4rVOP4B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 53 bytes

Returns a `Map<Char, Int>` associating characters to frequencies. The map keys are sorted in ASCII order (it's a `java.util.SortedMap` underneath.)

```
{s->s.associateWith{c->s.count{it==c}}.toSortedMap()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BCsIwEETv/YrFUwK2H1BsBT0JeurB85qmNlg3NdmKEPLtMRWc47wZZh6WJ0PpjROoEd3g9KsG0bEzdJdQtnDBeXfMZAsn4haaFHzZ@gq9t8og66vhMajVUnYhDoabRsVYse2sY93nvpAxDQvBEw0JCaGArHWR9YehAaexPxvSme1r2Gx@fM4PeCLxfyXWsJRFhHS4ocL@Cw)

Comment: Is this legal? I once got called out for defining my function in the header like you did here... Is that a legal code golf move because I'm genuinely not sure -> I can drop quite a few bytes on my Kotlin answer if so

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the consensus is but I recall it being legal for lambdas specifically. I've never been called out for it.

Comment: [This meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/how-do-we-calculate-the-length-of-lambda) states that for lambdas/anonymous functions only the function body is required. Since Kotlin can use type inference and you can indicate the function signature in the declaration, it seems to me like that counts as part of the assignment as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
SêDŠ¢ø
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@PAql6MLDi06vOP/f11dG10bG@1o7WgbbTtdXV07MLSxsYm1i7Wx0dXVs9EGAz0gRw9IAPl6dnYgBFSjB5IA83RBXG09AA)

Comment: [6 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@PAql6MLDi06vOP/f11dG10bG@1o7WgbbTtdXV07MLSxsYm1i7Wx0dXVs9EGAz0gRw9IAPl6dnYgBFSjB5IA83RBXG09AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) (in C locale), 32 bytes

```r
function(s)table(strsplit(s,''))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfmVeWWZyZlJOqEVxZrFecWpKTn5wI5Kn7OMc7@/v4OIa4qusoqDura2pypSnY6Cr8TyvNSy7JzM/TKNYsSQRpLC4pKi7IySzRKNZRByr7n6ah5F@WWqRgaWBgqKik@R8A)

`strsplit` the input character string by the empty string to separate its characters then `table` builds a contingency table of the unique character counts.

Comment: `identical(names(f("Over 9001!")), sort(names(f("Over 9001!"))))` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: @Giuseppe Right. Besides, my example is meaningless, if `table` sorts according to the locale in effect, so will `sort`.

Comment: @Giuseppe Yes, like this users will have a bad surprise.

Comment: Something [like this](https://tio.run/##K/qfmVeWWZyZlJOqEVxZrFecWpKTn5wI5Kn7OMc7@/v4OIa4qusoqDura2pypSnY6Cr8TyvNSy7JzM/TKNYsSQRpLC4pKi7IySzRKNZRByr7n6ah5F@WWqRgaWBgqKik@R8A) should be fine, just put a note saying "R (in C locale), 32 bytes" as the title, or something similar

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks, it's my first post and I really needed assistance.

Comment: No problem! There's a [chatroom for R golfing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81960/golfr); feel free to ping me (or any of the other R golfers) there and we'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>55</s>  <s>48</s>  <s>62</s> 57 bytes

```
a=>[...a].sort().map(c=>o.set(c,-~o.get(c)),o=new Map)&&o
```

output is a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

contrary to `Objects`, `Map` remember the order in which values where sets

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input")
let run = document.getElementById("run")
let output = document.getElementById("output")

run.onclick = () => {
  output.innerHTML = ""
  func(input.value).forEach((val, key) => output.innerHTML += `'${key}' => ${val}<br>`)
}

let func = a=>[...a].sort().map(c=>o.set(c,-~o.get(c)),o=new Map)&&o
```

```html
<input id="input"/>
<button id="run">run</button>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Thanks to Shaggy and Einacio for pointing my flaws

*-5 bytes thanks to Shaggy*

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to sort the output correctly.

Comment: I didn't see that I was confident object kept entries in the same order as they were added to it, I'll try to correct it later

Comment: i'm not sure about the input. it's defined in the question that it's a string, so splitting it should be part of your function as well

Comment: seems like i misinterpreted the `Input and output can be given using any convenient method.` part :/

Comment: `+1` for `Map`; don't think I've seen it used here before. But you have a lot more parentheses than you actually need and you can ditch the `get`: https://tio.run/##BcExDoMwDADAr1AGZEtg0bFD@AHiAYjBMqZqBXGURLDx9XD355OTxF/InbdVy@YKu2EmIl4oWcyAdHAAcYNR0gzSdrfNsmBrzutVjRywaayI@WS70m5f2KCeTo3Vp@/frxqxPA

Comment: @Shaggy actually I can't ditch the `get` look again your TIO, it doesn't count repeated characters. Still could remove some parentheses thank to you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 134 bytes

```forth
: f here 128 allot dup 128 erase -rot 0 do 2dup i + c@ + 1 swap +! loop drop
128 0 do dup i + c@ ?dup if i emit ." : ". cr then loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY4xb8MgEIX3/IoXr@iQnSxNgmjGdPLQoUOUwbUhjuQGhKFVf717kAwFdNz37t2BdSGOdLX5WpY9LEYTDJrNC7ppchFD8oVM6GYDCizVGBw2uXCDQH/k0GD@6TzEGpNzHkNwfpW7ivWf87XkltF83SJkhT0qiT4gjub@aD7wN/xjfvz1JhfZ16boU2R3ZpvDYTVXIFKklDiLsxKaiHTZSqmLvihFJJUoSzJIDsxS63zYI3OhEGUU/IzPQ7vPfnim7bcJ2NV1s34K72nbnra7t2v6OLG0/AE)

Limitation: won't work if any character occurs more than 256 times in a single string (to fix this requires an extra ~25 bytes)

#### Explanation

- Allocate an area of memory 128 bytes (cells if needed) wide to use as an array/dictionary
- Zero out all bytes/cells in that area
- Loop through string, for each character

  - Add ascii value to array starting address, then increment value at that address by 1
- When finished, loop through array/dictionary and output all chars/values that have a value other than 0

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                     \ start new word definition
  here 128 allot        \ allocate 128 bytes to use as an array
  dup 128 erase         \ fill array with zeros
  -rot                  \ stick array address behind string address
  0 do                  \ start counted loop from 0 to string-length - 1
    2dup                \ duplicate array and string address
    i + c@              \ get ascii value of next character in string
    + 1 swap +1         \ add to array address, then add 1 to the value in that array position
  loop                  \ end the loop
  drop                  \ drop the string address [no longer needed]
  128 0 do              \ start a counted loop from 0 to 127
    dup i + c@          \ get value at next array position
    ?dup                \ duplicate if >0
    if                  \ start an if block (if >0)
      i emit            \ output the character
      ." : ".           \ output ": " followed by the number of that char in the string
      cr                \ output a newline
    then                \ end the if block
  loop                  \ end the loop
;                       \ end the word definition
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 92 bytes

```
func[s][parse/case sort/case s[any[copy k[copy t skip thru any t](print[t length? to""k])]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYqxDsIwDER3vsJkAkUJICaQFVaYkGBgiDyENG1RUVslKRJfH9LCxtmyfffsXZEurtA0K/eQyqG1OpDujQ9uZU1wEDoff5c27Vvbrn9D810RQvPoIdZ@gMwg0qL3jzbqCE/XVrE@QOwYa2hJRKkEZu62YDD9ABNZbJbT88t52K3Xm/k/uw7b83G7O1XD7fhPhUCByDXXyFUO1VSISIoQhZDIJ8lsZB7ZS6XGzj9yBJMTo@WSpQ8)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5 (`-nF` `-M5.01` `-MList::Util=uniq`), <s>49</s> 41 bytes

41 bytes : `for$a(uniq sort@F){say"$a ",eval"y/$a//"}` doesn't work if input contains a slash.
Otherwise, 36 bytes : `for$a(uniq sort@F){say"$a "./\Q$a/g}` doesn't work because of `//g` in scalar context.

```
for$a(uniq sort@F){say"$a ".(()=/\Q$a/g)}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glUaM0L7NQoTi/qMTBTbO6OLFSSSVRQUlPQ0PTVj8mUCVRP12z9v9//7LUIgVLAwNDxX/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA2AtE9mcYmVVWhJZo4tyLD/unk5bgA)

[first answer](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9n1vpkGj9XyUxOr8oJVZbOy2/yMHNGshViY9VUytOrFRIzijSU1HSgwgBpRUM9PQcEv9bA@WUdOFA6X9iUnIKl39ZapGCpYGBoSJXcKmxv4expWd6abjHv/yCksz8vOL/uol5OW76@v91fU31DAwB)

Comment: [44 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlu1olvlZbW8fBzbo4sVJJJV4BIqSUll@kUJxfVKKQnVpZrJr9/79/WWqRgqWBgaHiv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv913QA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") (and fewer commandline options, even though we don't count those now)

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8tv0glUaM0L7NQoTi/qMTBTbO6OLFSSSVRQUkntSwxR6lSXyVRX1@p9v9//7LUIgVLAwNDxX/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA2AtE9mcYmVVWhJZo4tyLD/unluAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online") (with some extra cli options)

Comment: 9 characters longer but without the List::Util requirement: `@a{@F}=1;for$a(sort keys%a){say"$a ".(()=/\Q$a/g)}`

Comment: @msh210, thanks for the trick `@a{@F}=1` however first answer link is shorter also without List::Util, and options doesn't count now

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```
(x:String)=>x.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size).toSeq.sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 85 bytes

```cpp
#include<map>
auto f(std::string s){std::map<char,int>m;for(int c:s)m[c]++;return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5LDsMgDET3nMJKN6B@DgA0F6m6oIakSAEiPqsoZ0@BLLobj8dvjOt6nxGP42I9LkUb6dQ6ElVygImmrDlPOVo/Q2JbH@te4lfFm/V5dGIKkVYFyBNzL3xfryKaXKIHJ/Y/1YaKMcqNhLS0U9ZTRjYC0KswFJ8TPGvnoD6o1cBE3VU40DPAzwirbrsC6M9UM4OUgI/JxtTlwGE4rWQweN10zxqvlwbdyX78AA)

This solution makes use of several nice features of std::map:

1. It has a sorted iterator, with default lexicographic ordering.
2. The `[]`-operator default initializes members, in case of int it zeroes it.

Also, C++17 allows for golfing using `auto` and range-for loop.

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 120 bytes

```
	A =&ALPHABET
	I =INPUT
S	O =0
	A LEN(1) . X REM . A	:F(END)
R	I X =	:F(O)
	O =O + 1	:(R)
O	OUTPUT =GT(O) X 0 O	:(S)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBC4MwDIXP7a/IaVhKisJOkhY61m2Cs@IqCOJl5zEP@/90qUlI@Hjv5ffd3/vnnLPwYE@@Hx/@EpIUHdhuGOckXyKCrSXLfRiqRoGBBabw5OtFe6vCcFVyYv8CtnBUsiQiaGhEW01KRhHnxK/A3hPLbKwhsvRSksM5IxIS6VWvpB0iuqOJaHMbEaIhfZRhMLyYjXNl2GOKcBAW1OYP)

```
	A =&ALPHABET			;* alias for &ALPHABET (256 characters in ascending order)
	I =INPUT			;* read input
S	O =0				;* set counter to 0
	A LEN(1) . X REM . A	:F(END)	;* set X to first letter of A
					;* setting the REMainder to A
					;* and going to END if no letters remain
R	I X =	:F(O)			;* remove the first occurrence of X from I
					;* and output if none are left
	O =O + 1	:(R)		;* increment the counter, going to R
O	OUTPUT =GT(O) X 0 O	:(S)	;* if O > 0,
					;* output X 0 and O in that order
					;* then GOTO S
END
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 56 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...s].sort().reduce((a,b)=>(a[b]=(a[b]||0)+1)&&a,{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY3BCoJAEIbvPUV1kF3WGYxOweyeq0MeOnQQD6uuYogbuypE9eymPkA0M/zwMR/8dz1on7v60UFrCzOWcvRSJYjoU/TWdYyjM0WfG8Z0mHGpmE6yVC75fkdc7HgQ6PD14WNuW28bg42t2PkaX9B3rm6runyykm11lhd6yzlf/fbiwbj1IYp2mz9kAAIikYiEhAIAtSwRpSolAkASy@AEOMXEqNR8k4PzYyGYUeAfhdd@Hx/3h1PV346zPn4B)

Comment: Your output is incorrect. It is not in ASCII order, as can be seen with the input `Over 9001!`, where `v` is before `e` and `r`, which is not the case in ASCII order. Adding a `.sort()` would make it correct, at 56 bytes: `s=>[...s].sort().reduce((a,b)=>(a[b]=(a[b]||0)+1)&&a,{})`

Comment: @bigyihsuan,  thanks, indeed missed the ordering